# Will the auto-update function in Java 8 (JRE) automatic update to Java 9 on 21.9.2017?

Tags: java-9

We have a client side webstart application that is not yet ready for Java 9, it's rather unclear what will happen on 21.9.2017 with the auto-update option in the jRE.

If you have the latest Java 8 version with the auto-update enabled. Will version 9 be pushed to the client? Is disabling the auto-update function the only option to prevent this or will the auto-update only look for new versions of java 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Will version 9 be pushed to the client?

No.

New Java versions take some time to percolate to unsuspecting users:

- <strike>Even after the GA release of Java 9 will Java 8 remain the default download option at [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for about six months.</strike> (Turns out that was wrong.)
- Java 8 will receive further public updates [until at least September 2018](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html).
- Only when that time window draws to a close and Oracle published its official "end of public updates notice" will hesitant users have to consider switching to Java 9.
- A few months before the end of public support will the auto-updater propose an update to Java 9, but it will require user permission. (At least that's how it worked [between Java 7 and 8](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/01/java-8-auto-update-java-7-end)).

Answer (score 1):

Disabling *auto* update is not required, and is actually *counter productive*.

Keep in mind that people have legitimate reasons to continue using JREs or JDKs for Java 8 (probably *several* years into the future).

It is very much the same as with previous major releases of Java: ideally you *plan* about moving forward at some time - but there is absolutely no side *forcing* you when to make that move.

We *started* using Java 8 for production like 12 months ago - and we still have products out in the field that run on Java 6.

In that sense:

- you educate yourself about the changes that Java9 is offering
- you mainly identify a "path forward" for your deliveries around the new  module system
- you start experimenting with Java9 at some point ...

and then, when you decide "we are ready" - then you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I believe no,

as JAVA 9 has SO BIG change caused by its jigsaw(the change is so huge and make java 9 delay again and again ), such big chance has potential to break your current java application.

BTW: java 9 will finally release in this month.